# Access Apple Music Api outside iOS

Tags: ios, api, apple-music

I'm looking at creating a playlist creation tool for Apple Music.

Apple just release an api for iOS that allows this functionality.  Does anyone know if it is possible to use this api from NodeJS or some other service side technology?

Music Api Doucmentation

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_3.html

Apple Music Api Announcements

- https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/blog/new-apple-music-api/

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible with the current API. "An Apple Music API is now available that allows iOS Apps to directly control Apple Music playback for Members among other features." The API allows iOS to interact with the music app locally on the user's device. Not remotely from a server.

Comment: Not as of now. SKCloudServiceController is iOS only